# Checkbox Checked Event for multiple dynamic Checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have an aspx page where I dynamically create checkboxes and add them to a panel from data in a SQL database. I need to have only one checkbox checked at a time. I have tried and googled just about everything but I cannot get the right answer. How would I go about getting that done.

My code for creating the checkboxes

```
public void CreateTimeSelection()
        {
            DataSet times = GetTimes();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataTable table in times.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox chkTime = new CheckBox();
                    i += 1;
                    chkTime.ID = row["Time"].ToString();
                    chkTime.AutoPostBack = true;
                    chkTime.Text = row["Time"].ToString(); 
                    chkTime.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckChanged_click);
                    pnlTimeSlots.Controls.Add(chkTime);
                    pnlTimeSlots.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Code for Checkbox event handlers

```
protected void CheckChanged_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (chkSelect.Checked == true)
            {
                //set other checkboxes to false
            }                
        }
```

Comment: 'I need to have only one checkbox checked at a time.'.

That's called radio button, not check box.

Comment: You can use `RadioButtons` and their [`GroupName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Even if you use radiobuttons, you are still able to select everything at the same time.